# WLAN disconnected for sure?

Tags: network

If my PC has *NO* on-mainboard WLAN and there is *NO* WLAN-adapter card and *NO* USB WLAN-stick installed, how sure am I that there is really no WLAN connectivity possible ? I.e. can I really disconnect from the internet today ?

Background: 
Say I wanna really disconnect (most of the time, yes I know I need to update virus scanner lists, OS updates,...) from the internet (e.g. for security reasons). Just switch off your WLAN router, you say! OK, but there are many WLANs around in the air from the neighborhood. So I cannot 'escape' from potential WLAN connectivity. Can I make sure no piece of software (viruses, trojans, rootkits, NSA-spy software... you name it) on my PC gets (WLAN-) connected to the internet in some way. (Getting paranoid about this) I simply could ask if today's mainboards really have no WLAN enablement by default. (But maybe there are some physical EM-wave transmission limits that I am not aware of...)

Serious question, of course !
thx for your helpful comments

Answer (score 1):

If there is no WLAN hardware present, then by definition your laptop cannot possibly have WLAN capability.

But you then ask a slightly different question: "How can I be sure I have disconnected my computer from the internet?". You would guarantee this by ensuring there is no hardware that is capable of network communications. Here's my suggested guide for the paranoid:

1. Remove any USB WiFi "dongles".
2. Remove any network cabling.
3. Visually inspected the motherboard to rule out any PCIe (desktop) or [Mini-PCI/Mini-PCIe](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/MiniPCI_Express_slot) (laptop) wireless cards.
4. Continue inspecting the motherboard to rule out any [WWAN cards](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-75074) (that allow internet connectivity just like cellphones).
5. Continue inspecting the motherboard to ensure it does not include built-in WiFi (many modern motherboards [still don't](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/GRYPHON_Z87/#specifications)).
6. For good measure, enclose the computer in a [faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) with the mesh sized to block WiFi frequencies. Incidentally, [microwaves emit the same frequencies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18471/can-microwaves-affect-wifi-and-can-they-harm-us), so you can just buy microwave oven shielding in bulk :)
7. Bonus points: Modify the operating system and remove the network stack.

Congrats, you have now air-gapped your machine! If you've done all this, and can still get internet connectivity, I'll give you a million dollars.